# Batch file to handle random % character in FOR LOOP

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to pass file names as FOR loop parameters to a separate batch file. The problem is, if a file name contains special characters (especially %), the parameter doesnt go to the called script. EG -

The `FIRST_SCRIPT.bat` is as follows -

```
cd "C:\theFolder"
for /R %%a in (*.*) do call SECOND_SCRIPT "%%~a"
```

The `SECOND_SCRIPT.bat` is as follows -

```
ECHO %1
```

If a file name contains % eg. "% of STATS.txt", the output ends up being

```
of STATS.txt
```

Which is wrong. I have tried using `Setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion` but with little success

```
Setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /R %%a in (*.*) do (
SET "var=%%~a" 
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
call TEST_UPGRADE "%var%" "%%~a"
)
```

There are other stackoverflow answers, but they all need the % character to be known before hand. Since the file names are not in our control, these solutions won't work for us. Is there any way of handling this?

Thanks!

platform: cmd.exe for Windows XP

Comment: Maybe Forfiles, It would work fine if all your doing is calling a script. Type `forfiles /?`

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753551.aspx I checked. Looks like it is not available for windows XP :(

Comment: On the other hand.. i can package the forFiles.exe and use it. Will try it out and let you know.

Comment: Too many issues with xp. :(

Comment: `%` is the most difficult poison character to use in batch scripts and the script you are calling might also give you grief.  I'd suggest that you use a tool on your incoming files that will rename all `%` characters to `percent` rather than try to get your scripts to handle them.

Comment: Save you variables in a file or registry key and read them from the second batch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aacini shows a solution that would work with `%` and also `!` but it fails with carets `^`.

But the solution is simple.

First it's necessary to disable the delayed expansion to handle the exclamation marks.
The filename is now exactly in the `var` variable.
The problems with carets and percents are caused by the `CALL`.
This can be solved with the `CALL` itself by use only the second percent expansion phase of the `CALL` by using `%%var%%`.

```
Setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /R %%a in (*.*) do (
  SET "var=%%~a" 
  call TEST_UPGRADE "%%var%%"
)
```

The next problem is in the second.bat to display the filename.
This should be done with delayed expansion enabled to avoid problems with special characters, or you need always quotes.

```
set "var=%~1"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo Filename: !var!
```

Answer (score 4):

solution with a temp file:

`first.bat`

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
REM to escape the '%' use a second '%'
SET "var=40%% &off!.txt"
REM get a random temp file name
:loop
SET "tname=%temp%%random%%random%"
IF EXIST "%tname%" GOTO :loop
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
REM save the variable in the file
>"%tname%" (ECHO(!var!)
CALL "second.bat" "%tname%"
ENDLOCAL
```

---

`second.bat`

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
SET "tname=%~1"
<"%tname%" set/p"var="
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
ECHO !var!
DEL "%tname%" /F /Q
```

---

..output is:

```
40% &off!.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**: I added the enable/disable delayed expansion technique to avoid problems with exclamation-mark character.

```
@echo off
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /B *.txt') do echo %%a
echo/

for %%a in (*.txt) do (
SET "var=%%a" 
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
call :TEST_UPGRADE "!var:%%=%%%%!" "%%~a"
endlocal
)
goto :EOF

:TEST_UPGRADE
ECHO First: %1  Second: %2
exit /B
```

Output example:

```
% of STATS.txt
Discount of 10% in all.txt
Normal file.txt

First: "% of STATS.txt"  Second: " of STATS.txt"
First: "Discount of 10% in all.txt"  Second: "Discount of 10 in all.txt"
First: "Normal file.txt"  Second: "Normal file.txt"
```

Comment: This swaps `%` to `!` as a problem character.  Just so the OP knows that, and the script being called may still have issues.

Comment: @foxidrive: You are right! I added the toggling technique to avoid this problem.